# TryAcquireSRWLock* and _WIN32_WINNT

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

According to the documentation for

- [TryAcquireSRWLockShared](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405524.aspx) and
- [TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405523(v=vs.85).aspx)

these methods require at least Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2. To target this version of Windows one has to set `_WIN32_WINNT` to `_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` (0x0601) as documented in [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The methods are defined in synchapi.h. In my version of this file (SDK 8.1) they are guarded by the preprocessor directive `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)`.

For me this contradicts the documentation as 0x0600 refers to Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

---

**EDIT**

The common assessment of the issue from the comments seems to be that there is a bug in the SDK. `TryAcquireSRWLockShared` should only be available if `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0601`. The calls to `TryAcquireSRWLockShared` originate from the use of `std::shared_mutex`. There is a follow-up question on [How to use std::shared_mutex on Vista/Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325813)

Comment: They were definitely added in Windows 7. Looks like an include file bug.

Comment: this is incorrect condition `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)` in `synchapi.h` but this in practice does not affect anything. and this is file from sdk - absolute not depend from your vs version

Comment: @RbMm: I'd disagree, that failing to properly guard API calls were fine. What this leads to is, that you if you target Windows Vista, and are calling those API's, the application fails to start. Without the compiler telling you. This one breaks during testing (with little helpful diagnostic information), or at the customers'.

Comment: @IInspectable - before use some api - usual first read documentation about Minimum supported os version. if exist doubt (in documentation one, in headers another) - do some additional research. we can for example simply `#include <sdkddkver.h>` as is, which by default define `_WIN32_WINNT` to the latest (current sdk) version. but anyway use only api from say xp set. use higher `_WIN32_WINNT` version not prevent from restrict self in using some api

Comment: @RbMm That's not the point. The OP is clearly relying on the compiler to warn if he tries to use unsupported functions. The headers are incorrect.

Comment: @RbMm: Team A implements a module, that uses the API in question, and does everything right with their SFINAE and constexpr-if voodoo. That module is used by team B. Team B decides to drop their minimum supported client down to Vista. Who would *you* blame? I'd blame the SDK for not catching an error, that should be caught at compile-time.

Comment: The conditional declaration is still unchanged in the (now) current Windows SDK (10.0.16299.0).

Comment: They do update the "Minimum supported client" annotations.  Vista is retired and no longer supported.  But then again, the SDK headers are known to have bugs.  Hopefully this never will matter to you, state your minimum system requirements, you wouldn't want to have to support a Vista user.

Comment: @HansPassant E.g. [AcquireSRWLockShared](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms681934.aspx) still lists Windows Vista.

Comment: Well, that doesn't help you much.  You have to do this the right way: state your minimum requirements.  If it turns out that Vista doesn't have it then your program won't start.  And your requirements say why.

Comment: @HansPassant My minimum requirement is Server 2008. I need to support it at least for one more year. Yet my program no longer runs because it somehow requires `TryAcquireSRWLockShared` although I never call it in my code. `_WIN32_WINNT` is set to `0x0600`.

Comment: Why doesn't your question say this?  That's where it belongs, the only way you'll get an answer that actually helps you.

Comment: @HansPassant Before blaming anyone I wanted to make sure that a) I understand the problem completely and b) the problem is not caused by some misunderstanding of mine. I was planning on asking a separate question. I now updated this question. Thanks for your feedback. It is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you link against 3rd-party libraries (provided as object code), changing the preprocessor symbol wouldn't be of help anyway. That doesn't change the fact, though, that apparently there is a bug in the SDK headers. And very likely, whichever library does call one of those APIs fell into the same trap. Presumably, those libraries state their minimum requirements, and were under compiled under the assumption, that the preprocessor symbols would catch any requirement violation.

Comment: @IInspectable All 3rd party library I link against I do compile myself. In the respective code I could not find a call to `TryAcquireSRWLockShared`. Do you have any hints how I could figure out where the dependency originates from?

Comment: `TryAcquireSRWLockShared` is imported by *vccorlib140*, for example, i.e. the compiler support library. You'd probably have to use the XP toolset to get around that.

Comment: @IInspectable Your comment helped a lot! After switching the toolset the application no longer compiled. The compile error is caused by the use of `std::shared_mutex` and `std::shared_lock`. I was then able to confirm that the calls to `TryAcquireSRWLockShared` originate from the use of `std::shared_mutex` and `std::shared_lock` in a SSCCE using either `std::shared_mutex` and `std::shared_lock` or their non-shared counterparts.

Comment: I still believe that your initial instinct to break the issue down into different questions was correct. The original version of this question was perfectly fine, and if you have access to Vista/Server 2008, you can verify the SDK bug by running [DUMPBIN /EXPORTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dash-exports) against kernel32.dll, and provide an answer.

Comment: The follow-up question (*"How to use `std::shared_mutex` on Vista/Server 2008?"*) appears to be a self-contained question, especially since the MSDN documentation for [shared_mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/shared-mutex) could benefit from some clarification. The implications of the warning halfway down are not immediately obvious (i.e. you need to use the XP toolset in VS2015 and above, when targeting Windows versions prior to Windows 7).

Comment: Addendum: The command line to execute would be `dumpbin /exports kernel32.dll | findstr "TryAcquire"`. That'll immediately show the respective exports, if present.

Comment: @IInspectable The reputation for answering the questions is due to you I would say. Otherwise I will have to postpone an answer until Monday when I am back in the office and hopefully have access to a Windows Server 2008 VM.

Comment: The functions were introduced in Windows Vista, so the `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)` guard is correct. The "Minimum supported client" is Windows 7 because Windows Vista [is no longer supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22882/windows-vista-end-of-support).

Comment: @RaymondChen But code using them does not run on Server 2008? See my follow-up https://stackoverflow.com/q/49325813

Comment: Oh wait, I'm confused. I was looking at `InitializeSRWLock`, not `TryAcqureSRWLock`. Those are indeed new for Windows 7. I'll file an SDK bug.