# How to use std::shared_mutex on Vista/Server 2008?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++17

This is a follow-up question to [TryAcquireSRWLock* and _WIN32_WINNT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49317541/)

As it seems there is a bug in the Windows SDK 8.1 and newer (up to at least the current 10.0.16299.0) making the methods [TryAcquireSRWLockShared](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405524.aspx) and [TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405523(v=vs.85).aspx) available for compilations targeting Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008. This causes applications containing calls to these methods being unable to execute on Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 since they are ultimately only available starting from Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

It seems that the implementation of [std::shared_mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/shared-mutex) in the Windows SDK 8.1 makes use of [TryAcquireSRWLockShared](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405524.aspx) and [TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405523(v=vs.85).aspx). Thus using [std::shared_mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/shared-mutex) renders the application unable to execute on Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008.

The documentation also states

> Warning
>
> Beginning in Visual Studio 2015, the C++ Standard Library
>   synchronization types are based on Windows synchronization primitives
>   and no longer use ConcRT (except when the target platform is Windows
>   XP). The types defined in <shared_mutex> should not be used with any
>   ConcRT types or functions.

However, when using the platform toolset v140_xp the compiler complains about not knowing [std::shared_mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/shared-mutex) at all.

How can I use [std::shared_mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/shared-mutex) and still target Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008?

Comment: By your own admission, `std::shared_mutex` uses APIs that don't exist on Vista/2008. You will have to use another solution to your problem. Or, you will have to provide your own implementations of `TryAcquireSRWLockShared` and `TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive` for OS versions that don't have them available natively.

Comment: I'd say you can't. `v140_xp` was grudgingly added by Microsoft after the uproar when they unilaterally dropped XP support. It lets you target XP with the new compiler, it doesn't necessarily provide all the new features of the new compiler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The warning on the documentation page for [std::shared_mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/shared-mutex) implies, that there is an implementation, that doesn't use Win7+ APIs, as long as you target Windows XP.

Comment: The SRW locks are not upgradable anyway, I think they are not much useful. I have implemented it using plain mutex functions, check my RWMutex https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1053865/RWMutex-A-shared-exclusive-recursive-mutex

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't. But you can use alternate implementations. There's `boost::shared_mutex`. Or if you are using Qt, you can use QReadWriteLock.